# Fix User permission (UID changed)

Tags: unix, user

I changed the UID of an user, (cos I was having problems with file permission), now this user can access or see any file...

any ideas how to fix?

I executed

usermod -u UID username
 with the old UID but it saying that uid exist...

any ideas how to solve?
thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Add the `-o` option and it will allow using non-unique/duplicate UID

```
usermod -o -u UID username
```

Also quite a few other things you could try for debugging.

```
usermod --help
```

for a full list